# SSRS SWITCH colours based on two columns

Tags: reporting-services, switch-statement

I have a dataset with several depots and stock columns based on each depot.

```
=SWITCH(Fields!ID2_0m_Avlalon_Gate_Barrier.Value <=100 , "Red", Fields!ID2_0m_Avlalon_Gate_Barrier.Value >100, "Green")
```

The above code works fine.

I am trying to set a back fill property for each stock column to change based on the depot selected AND the amount of items in stock.

So far I have made a basic switch work for the column but cannot figure how to then add the depot equation into it:

```
=SWITCH(Fields!ID2_0m_Avlalon_Gate_Barrier.Value <=10 AND Fields!Depot_Location.Value = 'Carlisle', "Green",
Fields!ID2_0m_Avlalon_Gate_Barrier.Value >10 AND Fields!Depot_Location.Value = 'Carlisle', "Red"
)
```

I get the following error:

> The BackgroundColor expression for the text box ‘ID2_0m_Avlalon_Gate_Barrier’ contains an error: [BC30201] Expression expected.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What depot equation do you want to add?

Comment: apologies my question didn't make too much sense reading it back, The above code I have posted does not work in the Fill parameter. 

A basic switch statement without the department in the code worked fine but I need it to work in the way I'm trying above.

I have a several depots e.g Manchester, Preston, Carlisle.

I need the back colour to switch based on the depot name value and the number of stock field value.

Comment: @Benzz `'Carlise'` should be `"Carlise"`. SSRS uses double quote for strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the single quotes in `'Carlisle'`.

Try `"Carlisle"` instead.

Comment: Something so simple! - Thank you!